# about AT&T assembly syntax (%esp,1)

Tags: c, assembly, att

When I read some disassembly code, for I am not up on AT&T syntax, I do not know what some code like (%esp,1)  means.

```
11      printf("%x", a);
0x401386        <main+182>:    movl  $0x1,0x4(%esp,1)
0x40138e        <main+190>:    movl  $0x40300d,(%esp,1)
0x401395        <main+197>:    call  0x401810 <printf>
```

Could someone tell what it does mean? Thank you!

Comment: `0x4(%esp,1)` is same as `[esp*1 + 0x4]` in Intel syntax.

Comment: But...it seems that [esp+ 0x4*1] is more common? --sorry for my poor English.  0x4(%esp,2) seems no practical significance?

Comment: What's common is something like `[esp+eax*4+16]` (in which `eax` is an index to a 32-bit integer array located at `esp+16`). That's why "scale" exists in the addressing mode.

Comment: *"is more common?"* What's more common *odes note matter*. What *the tool in front of you used* matters.

Comment: See also the [AT&T syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) for more details on the syntax, and links to more docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wikibook seems to have some information about the GNU assembler and its AT&T syntax:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax

I also found these two sources of documentation on Gas, but they don't seem to be very clear or useful:

1. http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AsmTools/Gas/GasDoc/as_toc.html
2. http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/index.html

Answer (score 2):

```
                              ; Decompiled, sort of, back to C
                              ; ==============================
    movl  $0x1,0x4(%esp,1)    ; %esp[1] = 1 (the "1" really means, "add 4")
    movl  $0x40300d,(%esp,1)  ; %esp[0] = "%x"
    call  0x401810 <printf>   ; push return address and branch to printf
```

It seems that the compiler knows that *a* is equal to *1*, and that it already has adjusted the stack pointer downward to make room for the arguments. Perhaps it combined pushing space onto the stack with the function prologue.

In general, the addressing modes look like...

```
r    ; register
(r)  ; memory, register contains the address
8(r) ; memory, displacement of 8 off the register
```

Comment: Thanks! But...",1" is useless?

Comment: x86 has indexed addressing modes, the ",1" is not needed but might have been ,2 or ,4 had the index feature been used. It's just the disassembler being uninspired.

Comment: So, 0x4(%esp,2) means *(%esp + 2*0x4), 0x4(%esp,4) means *(%esp + 4*0x4), and 0x4(%esp,3) is forbidden?

Comment: "It seems that the compiler knows that a is equal to 1", yes, "a" is qualified by "const"